# tsconfig.json path pattern

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc, tsconfig-paths

Is there any way to include files by path pattern? For example, I am currently doing this in my scripts:

`import '../../../../myresource/src/shared/my-interface'`

However, I would like to simply use this:

`import '@myresource/shared/my-interface'`

Notice that in the last example, specifying the 'src' folder has been skipped. Also, 'myresource' would be changed to match any folder at that path ('myresource', 'myresource1', 'myresource2', etc..), so I would like to know if there's any solution which would not require me to add each specific folder inside the 'paths' object of the tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `tsconfig.json` ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-parm-vgbxvj?file=/src/index.ts)):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also customize the paths for your needs.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["*", "dir1/*"]
    }
  }
}
```